# VB.Net Iterating over DataGridView.SelectedRows uses lots of RAM, DGV.Rows doesn't?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, loops, datagridview

I am iterating over selected items in my DGV like so.

```
For i = 0 To dgv.SelectedRows.Count - 1

Next
```

Even that loop, with no code inside, RAM usage climbs from ~40mb to ~70mb, depending on how many rows I have selected.

Now, if I do pretty much the same thing, with the Rows property instead, RAM usage stays the same when executing the loop.

```
For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1

Next
```

What is the difference between the 2?  Why does SelectedRows nearly double my apps RAM consumption?

Comment: Are you selecting the rows before iterating `0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1`?  Selecting a row causes it to become _unshared_ and will thus consume more memory.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yeah, I have all rows selected except 1, for both loops.  Same result, iterating over SelectedRows causes the RAM usage spike, Rows doesn't.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue.  Retrieving SelectedRows does create a new collection ([see source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2cc4e2a42be6fd3c)), but that should not consume the memory increase that you are seeing.  Perhaps someone else will have some insights.

Comment: @TnTinMn Alright, well I am using VS 2017 .NET 4.5.1 I believe, that might matter.  Looking at the performance profiler during the testing.  FYI I'm iterating over 1 million rows, this is a stress test/see where I can get some performance improvements kinda thing.

Comment: `"I'm iterating over 1 million rows"` - egads! I think you should have mentioned that earlier as it is beyond reason to anticipate such an abuse of a UI control.  Kidding aside, with that many rows I have verified a large increase in memory consumption (in my test a ~3.5 times increase) on retrieving the `SelectedRows` property.  To determine that cause will require more effort than I am willing to commit to analyzing the source code though.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yeah, 1 million rows is rough, a part of me wishes DGV could handle it, but I understand it's impractical from the users perspective anyways.  I'm just going to add paging, it seems to be the way to go with a large amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedRows creates a new ArrayList containing selected items every time it is accessed and the loop condition is accessing it for every iteration to get the count.

You could store the result in a variable to only have this overhead occur once.

```
Dim selectedRows = dgv.SelectedRows
For i = 0 To selectedRows.Count - 1

Next
```